# I can't put the text in the center of the image (over the image) and won't change position when it is being minimize or maximize

Tags: html, css, image, text, position

I want to put a text (the subtitle-text) inside the image which has a alignment center. This needs to be center even if it is being minimize or maximize. I tried to use transform and put left and top: 50% but it doesn't work and keep overflowing in the screen (outside the image). can someone help me? I did try everything that is in net and also use sample from this platform but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
     .title {
       position: absolute;
       text-align: center;
       color: #fff;
       font-weight: 900;
       font-style: bold;
       font-size: 1rem;
       font-family: b;
     }
     .fa {
       position: relative;
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
       margin-bottom: 1rem;
     }
     .fa img {
       width: 30%;
       height: 1.5rem;
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
     .subtitle {
       position: relative;
       display: flex;
       margin: 0.5rem;
       text-align: center;
       align-items: center;
     }
     .subtitle img {
       width: 23%;
     }
     .subtitle .subtitle-text{ 
       position: absolute;
       text-align: center;
       justify-content: center;
       color: #fff;
       font-weight: 900;
       font-style: bold;
       font-size: 0.8rem;
       font-family: b;
       left: 4%;
     }
     .main {
       padding: 1rem 0;
       overflow-x: hidden;
     }
     .main .box{
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       text-align: center;
       color: #292B32;
       margin-right: 1.5rem;
       font-size: 0.65rem;
       font-weight: 400;
       font-family: b;
     }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="fa">
      <div class="title">title</div>
      <img src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Maximus-Tamur/publication/354575794/figure/fig2/AS:1067950245154821@1631630588806/Rectangle-b-Cut-out-the-existing-rectangular-shape-through-one-of-the-diagonal-lines-c.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="subtitle">          
        <div class="subtitle-text">subtext</div>
        <img src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Maximus-Tamur/publication/354575794/figure/fig2/AS:1067950245154821@1631630588806/Rectangle-b-Cut-out-the-existing-rectangular-shape-through-one-of-the-diagonal-lines-c.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may center the subtitle text by modifying the CSS for the `.subtitle-text` class. You set the `left` attribute to 4% which is pushing the text to the right by 4%, Instead of using `left:4%`, you can use `left:11%` and add `bottom:10%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to center the text within its container

This is the changed CSS script:

```
.subtitle .subtitle-text {
 position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: b;
  left: 11%;
  bottom: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%
}
```

you may also add `width:100%` to ensure that the text takes up the full width of its container.

Comment: this code center the subtitle-text in the center of the screen and not in the image.

Comment: I'll modify the css

Comment: I editted the code @Yesha, I tested it and it works, please check

Comment: didn't recognize the ph tag in your profile, salamat pooo

Comment: no problem, laban!